# Automatically synchronize between Flowcharts (form of PERT charts) and Gantt charts?

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, gantt

**Summary**

I'm seeking project-management software tools (be they online/cloud or installed software) that support automatic synchronizing between [Flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) (a form of PERT charts) and [Gantt charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).

Which solutions provide this?

**Details**

The Gantt support needs to support auto-dependency "links" between tasks. (There are tools that support a Gantt layout but with no auto-task-dependency management--eg: [monday.com](https://monday.com/)--but that's insufficient for my requirements.)

My initial research has not yet found anything. I've looked at several tools, but I'm far from completing a comprehensive search. Microsoft Project appears to support PERT charts, but to what extent it can do the above is currently unclear.  At this point, I'm not optimistic I'll find anything, but I'm early in my search.

EDIT: [WBS Schedule Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhF8ZfUajpw) shows some initial promise.

Comment: WBS Schedule Pro, at first glance, provides the most-encouraging capabilities I've yet seen. Check out the overview video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhF8ZfUajpw

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! Software recommendations are off-topic here. Please, take a look at "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" article.

Answer (score 1):

[]project-open[](http://www.project-open.com/) is an open-source project management server. The latest V5.0 version from CVS supports scheduling with end-to-start dependencies in the JavaScript client. In order to build a solution to your problem you would have to:

1. Import activities from your flowchart into the ]po[ PostgreSQL database
2. Create the end-to-start dependencies in the ]po[ DB
3. Run the ]po[ GanttEditor for scheduling

Disclosure: I'm a member of the ]po[ team.